# Taking a link title from a query parameter & displaying it somewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Any idea how I could grab the link title from the query parameter and have it display somewhere on my landing page? I'm thinking a heading where it says "Welcome {whatever the link title is} and changes depending on which link has been clicked.

```
<a ng-click="link.clicks=link.clicks+1" href="#/landing?=link={{link.linktitle}}"><span>{{ link.linktitle }}</span></a>
```

My link shows up like this in the browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/landing?=broncos
```

I just need the Broncos part or whatever the link title is.

It should look like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTHBk.png)

All of the heavy functionality is happening inside of a controller.js file but I need to show the "(link title) are awesome! part on an HTML page

Comment: You can use $location.search().link to get the qury params

Comment: Hi Muhammed, I tried that but I couldn't figure out how to narrow it down to the exact parameter I needed since I need to target a link inside of a link.

Comment: Can you show me what are you getting when you print just $location.search()?

Comment: This is the code I was using: $scope.location = $location;
   $scope.$watch('location.search()', function() {
       $scope.target = ($location.search()).link;
   }, true
 );

   $scope.changeTarget = function(name) {
       $location.search('link', name);
   }

Comment: Can u print $location.search()?

Comment: I'm getting $location not defined or $scope not defined errors in my console.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var str = "http://localhost:3000/#/landing?=link%3Dbroncos";
var pagenum = str.match(/link(.*)/)[1];
alert(pagenum); // %3Dbroncos
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7nbLs5ww/

**EDIT:**

```
var str = "localhost:3000/#/landing?=broncos";
var pagenum = str.match(/landing\?\=(.*)/)[1];
alert(pagenum); // broncos
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7nbLs5ww/1/

**EDIT 2:**

```
var str = "http://www.your_url.com/landing/?link=wolverines";
var pagenum = str.match(/\?link\=(.*)/)[1];
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pagenum[0].toUpperCase() + pagenum.slice(1)+" are awesome!";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7nbLs5ww/2/

Comment: simplify your code and post it... the above code works but you need to adapt it to your code...

Comment: Yes of course.. because the "=link" misses..I did an update to the answer

Comment: now i'm getting "cannot get innerHTML of null". I'm doing all of my javascript inside of a controller.

Comment: I've posted an example of what the end result should look like in my question above ^ thanks for your help @Konstantinos

Comment: It's working fine when I practice in jfiddle but when I add it to my code its doing nothing. I have the div in the HTML for my landing page and the code inside of my controller.js file. The only thing I can think of is that the landing page can't see the code because its out of scope maybe.

Comment: I've changed the variables to $scope.str = "" and $scope.pagenum but I'm still getting errors from DOM part @Konstantinos